# Extracting Data from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have XML file containing data from multiple sources which I am trying to extract for analysis. But I am not able to extract the data.

Could anyone enlighten me on the procedure to extract the data while keeping the heading and unit of the data?

The file is attached [xml file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5920flhajhg2cnt/00001.xml?dl=0).

The snap of the data is also attached here:

[image]

The only output I can get is the header and I couldn't load the data into python for further analysis. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to use [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

```
with open("00001.xml", "r") as file:
    raw = file.read()

import xmltodict
data = xmltodict.parse(raw)
print(data)
```

This prints out:

```
OrderedDict([('logs',
              OrderedDict([('@xmlns', 'http://www.witsml.org/schemas/1series'),
                           ('@xmlns:xsi',
                            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'),
                           ('@version', '1.4.1.1'),
                           ('log',
                            OrderedDict([('@uidWell', 'W-508420'),
                                         ('@uidWellbore', 'B-508420'),
                                         ('@uid', 'L-508421-Time'),
                                         ('nameWell', '15/9-F-5'),
                                         ('nameWellbore',
                                          '15/9-F-5 - Main Wellbore'),
                                         ('name', 'Real Time SLB - Time Log'),
                                         ('serviceCompany', 'Schlumberger'),
                                         ('creationDate',
                                          '2007-12-18T13:28:58.000Z'),
```

You get an ordered dict which values you can access like any other dicts values.

If you want to get tabular data I suggest to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data["logs"])
df.head()
```

Comment: My main concern is getting the data in a tabular form......i appreciate your support for demystifying the subject.Could you guide on getting the data in tabular form

Comment: Thank you so much @petezurich now I can start cleaning data

Comment: @AbhishekKumar You´re welcome. And good luck with your project!